# routing DRF with multi slashes lookup_field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i have views (readonlymodel)

```
class Test(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Test.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'art'
    serializer_class = TestSerializer
    @action(methods=['GET'], detail=True)
    def chars(self, request, art):
        ....
```

also urls:

```
router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'api/test', Test)
```

I need lookup_field to work for art with multiple slashes. Example art: "first_product/test"
But action chars is also needed. Example 'first_product/test/chars'

Examples of queries that should work:

```
0.0.0.0:8000/api/test/first_product/test
0.0.0.0:8000/api/test/first_product/test/chars
0.0.0.0:8000/api/test/second_product
0.0.0.0:8000/api/test/second_product/chars
```

I tried to do it through lookup_value_regex, but unfortunately it didn't work out that way, either /chars doesn't work, or with /chars works, but it doesn't see without it. Those works either this or that:

```
0.0.0.0:8000/api/test/first_product/test
0.0.0.0:8000/api/test/first_product/test/chars
```

i tried:
this worked for 'test/teste/chars'

```
lookup_value_regex = '.*?(?=\/chars)'
```

for 'test/test'

```
lookup_value_regex = '.*'
```

Comment: What value did you try with `lookup_value_regex`?

Comment: I tried:
lookup_value_regex = '.*?(?=\/chars)'
this worked for 'test/test/chars'
and 
lookup_value_regex = '.*'
for 'test/test'

Comment: Added to the question text